# Bootstrap Styling is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

In my current ASP.Net core I am trying to do the boot strap styling for search component on the page. I want the UI to look like

[image]

where the label/input box and the Search button to appear in the middle of the screen and the Create New To show in the same row but to appear right side of the screen

I have tried like below

```
<div class="center">
    <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2 form-check-inline mr-0">
                        <label class="col-auto" for="holiday"> Find by Holiday </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2  form-check-inline mr-0">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" />
                        <a class="btn btn-link" asp-action="Index">Back to Full List</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2  form-check-inline mr-0" style="text-align:right">
                        <a class="btn btn-info" asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the UI shows up like below

[image]

Can anyone help say what is that I am missing why all the things appear so close, I tried adding the `style="text-align:right"` so the Create new will appear towards the right

***** EDIT *****

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You could try this way to implement accordingly as per your
> expectations like below:

***`Asp.net Submit Form With CSS`***

```
<div class="center">
    <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="col-auto" for="holiday" style="margin-top:10px;"> Find by Holiday </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: -50px;" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a class="btn btn-link" asp-action="Index">Back to Full List</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <a class="btn btn-info" asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

***`Output`***

[image]

> ***`Note:`*** You could set your `CSS` in different class file. I have shown you how could you achieve that using inline `CSS` snippet. You
> could use separate file as well. But this is the right and convenient
> way to do what you are trying to.

Comment: Thank you !! I tried exactly the same code but you can see in the question how I am seeing the screen

Comment: I removed the .center css and tried do the same way as everything inline.. But I am not seeing the same behavior as you are seeing in the screen

Comment: I swaped both the div classes         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"> and it is looking better

Comment: Its actually preference centric. I basically focused on the gap between label and textbox which seems alright I think So the problem resolved?

Comment: It resolved.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is caused by your class 'col-md-2'. You can change all of 'col-md-2' to 'col-md-4' to test.

Comment: No it didnot help too

Comment: Then you can replace `style="text-align:right" ` to `style="justify-content:end"` It should work with class'form-check-inline'.

Comment: Thanks !! It helped a little but I cannot move it towards the right of the screen. I added an image in the question

Comment: hmm, it is hard to guess here, it would be great that if you can show the parent div width of button 'create new'. 
But firstly, please try to change all  'col-md-2' to 'col-md-4'.

Comment: It seems one of the button's ascendant is not in full width, or there is margin-right / padding-right giving the space in the page.

Comment: I updated the question It is looking different

Comment: I suggest you to keep 
`<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2  form-check-inline mr-0">
  <a class="btn btn-link" asp-action="Index">Back to Full List</a>
</div>
`

Answer (score -1):

try adding `ml-auto` on the 'Create New' button

Comment: No it didnot help either